# feign.RetryableException: Unexpected end of file from server executing POST

Tags: consul, spring-cloud-feign

```
feign.RetryableException: Unexpected end of file from server executing POST http://conf-management-online/confLoader
    at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:268)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:129)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.getConfs(Unknown Source)
```

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:866)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at feign.Client$Default.convertResponse(Client.java:109)
    at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:105)
```

Already add prefer-ip-address and retry on my config

```
Spring.cloud.consul.discovery.prefer-ip-address: True

retry:
  enabled: true
  max-attempts: 20
  max-interval: 2000
  initial-interval: 1000
```

myapplication
Springboot cloud + openfeign + consul

```
spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:3.1.3
spring-retry: 1.3.1
```

Problem is how can I avoid this error and make sure That Feign retires using the ip:port?